# Notification when display name of existing AD record is changed

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have several external systems that work of the Display Name value in Active Directory.  When a new account in AD is created, corresponding accounts in other applications are automatically created. When someone changes the display name of an existing user, the login for that user is no longer valid in other systems.

Is there a way to get an email notification or similar whenever the display name for an existing record is changed in AD?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to your domain controllers**

Active Directory has certain "audit policies" that describes what it generates events for (in the Windows Event Viewer on each domain controller). Each can be turned on or off. The "Account Management" audit policy would generate events for changes to accounts. I believe the event contains the attributes changed. You can read more about those policies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/monitoring-active-directory-for-signs-of-compromise).

If that policy is enabled in your environment, and you have access to the domain controllers, you could setup scheduled tasks on each domain controller with [event-based triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-triggers#event-based-triggers) that fires when event ID 4738 happens (event IDs are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor)).

The scheduled task can then run a script that can do whatever you want it to. There are instructions [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/otto/2011/08/24/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/) on how to run a PowerShell script on an event and to get the event that triggered it in the script.

**If you don't have access to your DCs**

Otherwise, you would need to keep a separate database mapping a unique identifier of each account (like the `objectGuid`) to the display name, and have a scheduled job that updates that and notices changes. You can read [here](https://morgansimonsen.com/2008/08/12/how-to-use-the-whencreated-and-whenchanged-attributes-to-search-for-objects-in-active-directory/) about how to search AD for accounts changed after a certain date, which you can use to only find accounts that have been changed since the last time the job ran.